# Risks of running asp net aplication with an administrator account

Tags: asp.net, security

I'd like to know which are the security risks of running an asp net application with an administrator account.

I might end up doing this and I'd like to be aware of the known security wholes I would have.

I'm connecting to a sql server using sql authentication so excessive privileges to execute queries is out of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having trouble coming up with a scenario where this would actually make sense -- you can always delegate specific permissions to a named user to get them the specific admin-style rights they need.

As for the question at hand, direct risk isn't any greater than any other web application inasmuch as a web app is a big honking hole through your firewall. The indirect risk is very, very scary. You are trying to turn the clock back to 2000 when IIS5 was setup to run as local system making every single case of "IIS can be made to run arbitrary commands" into "anyone can own your box over port 80."

If you do have to do this, I'd consider putting firewalls behind the server too. That way, when it does get rooted, you've got some defenses. I'd also use unique accounts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should rarely need to run IIS under an administrative account. It's usually a sign of poorly written code. For example, I have seen it done when an app needs to shell out a batch job or executable, and needs to run those files under admin context to work (ie. very poorly coded applications).

You don't want to run any services under admin context. Not your IIS service, and especially not your database service. Any exploit triggered on your system will take on admin privileges, leading to a complete box compromise. Notice that in newer versions of Windows, both client and server, there are much fewer services running as either admin or system. This is due to Microsoft's own learnings that running apps under excessive privileges is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The risk is completely endless; a single mistake in your code, or an as-yet-undiscovered IIS/ASP.NET security vulnerability and you would be giving potential crackers complete, unfettered access to the server.

Compared to running it under the default account(s), where access would be pretty restricted.

There's really no reason to need to do this anymore, especially with the newer Windows servers, ASP.NET versions and IIS.